# SQLite order by date and group by

Tags: sqlite

I've got a `SQLite` table which looks like this:

```
channel     message     time
123         hello       2014-03-25 21:33:52
123         there       2014-03-25 22:31:00
222         hi also     2014-01-22 10:19:00
222         bye         2014-01-22 11:29:00
```

Now I want to get the latest message for each `channel` and order all the results by `DESC`.

What I got so far is:

```
SELECT * from history WHERE GROUP BY channel order by date(time) DESC;
```

This returns the latest message for each `channel` but the results are not in order.

Im getting:

```
222         bye         2014-01-22 11:29:00
123         there       2014-03-25 22:31:00
```

Channel `123` should be on the top since its the newest one.

Any ideas what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: with-out condition will it work? :? and try to `order by time` only

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just tried to order my data wich uses date and time, and it works, but only for DATE or TIME(names of my fields)

In your case, the name of the column is "time" so why do you use `date(time)` instead of simply `time`? try to order it simply with:

```
SELECT * from history WHERE GROUP BY channel order by time DESC;
```

Answer (score 0):

In Sqlite database the date type is not of NSDate type it acts as a string so it will not order your records in according to the date. You have to do it with some other way.